# Forcing microphone input when bluetooth is on

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have two Services: the first records with bluetooth but in the second I want to recorder the voice by the microphone input, how can I do if the bluetooth is always on? thanks.

I've tried with

```
 am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

 am.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
 am.stopBluetoothSco(); 
 am.setMicrophoneMute(false);
```

but it doesn't record through the microphone if the bluetooth is On.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to achieve this is a way that is guaranteed to work across all/most devices and Android versions. But there are a couple of things that you could try:

1. Use the `CAMCORDER` AudioSource. This will, at least on some devices, give one of the built-in microphones higher priority than the BT microphone. It should be noted that using `CAMCORDER` could lead to the microphone being tuned for far-field recording (recording something that is, say, a few meters distant), which might be a problem if you actually intend to a near-field recording.
2. Tell the `AudioPolicyManager` that even though you've enabled BluetoothSco, you don't want it to be used for recording:

```
 Class<?> audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
 Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
 // 2 == FOR_RECORD, 0 == FORCE_NONE
 setForceUse.invoke(null, 2, 0);
```

Since implementations of the `AudioPolicyManager` differ between vendors, it's not guaranteed that every implementation will see this as a cue to not use the BT mic for recordings.

Comment: I already use the setting CAMCORDER but doesn't seem to have priority over bluetooth. For the second, where do I write this code?, how do I specify that is the bluetooth that is not to be used for recording only in the second Service? Thanks

Comment: _"where do I write this code"_ Before you start the recording that you want to use the internal mic.

Answer (score 0):

To record from phone Mic when bluetooth device is connected you just set a flag (Swith) if Flag is notSet(off) dont registerReceiver just call normal startRecord() method.  when the flag is SET means record from Bluetooth headset by registering BroadcastReceiver and inside onReceive() check AudioManager state and start recording.

The below code might help you.

Record Button

here bluetooth is the flag variable (switch)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            if (bluetooth.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Recording",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                Register();


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Normal Recording",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 
                Normal();

            }
        }
    });
```

****Normal recording(Phone MIC) even when bluetooth is ON ****

```
protected void Normal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!mIsRecording) {
        button.setText(stopRecordingLabel);
        mIsRecording = true;
        mRecorder.startRecording();
        mRecording = getFile("raw");
        startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
    } else {
        button.setText(startRecordingLabel);
        mIsRecording = false;
        mRecorder.stop();
        File waveFile = getFile("wav");
        try {
            rawToWave(mRecording, waveFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, "Recorded to " + waveFile.getName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Recording From Bluetooth Device
when device is connected you will get callback

```
protected void Register() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, "Inside rcv " ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int state = intent.getIntExtra(
                    AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);

            Log.d("Tag", "Audio SCO state: " + state);

            if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) {
                /*
                 * Now the connection has been established to the */bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onrecive",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onrecive",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (!mIsRecording) {
                    button.setText(stopRecordingLabel);
                    mIsRecording = true;
                    mRecorder.startRecording();
                    mRecording = getFile("raw");
                    startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
                } else {
                    button.setText(startRecordingLabel);
                    mIsRecording = false;
                    mRecorder.stop();

                    File waveFile = getFile("wav");
                    try {
                        rawToWave(mRecording, waveFile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this,
                            "Recorded to " + waveFile.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                unregisterReceiver(this);
                am.stopBluetoothSco();
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED));

    Log.d("Start Bluetooth", "starting bluetooth");
    am.startBluetoothSco();

}
```